# Xamarin.iOS AutoLayouts (Cirrious.FluentLayout) and PresentViewController weird behvaior

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios, ios-autolayout, cirrious.fluentlayout

I am seeing constraints errors in my output window when I invoke a UIViewController using PresentViewController

Here is what my view heirarchy looks like:

1. MainViewController (RootViewController)

   - Outer MainVC Button
   - Nested UINavigationController (Nav1)

     - FirstViewController (Nav1.RootViewController)

       - Nested FirstVC Button
2. MyModalViewController (Presented by invoking PresentViewController)

   - dismiss button

[image]
[image]

Everything works as expected when MyModalViewController is shown from the Outer MainVC Button, but when I do the same from the Nested FirstVCButton and dismiss it to return back, I get constraint errors and the Nav1 is gone from the MainViewController

[image]

I just want to understand why this is happening and any potential workarounds are also welcome.

Full Source Code replicating this issue can be found here 
https://github.com/raghurana/XamarinIosAutoLayoutBug

---

### Edit

It's a requirement to present MyModalViewController (well modally, thus PresentViewController instead of Push Or Show) due to UX design requirements.